# I want to Display custom woocomerce meta box in orders list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, metabox

I run a WooCommerce store and work with lots of delivery companies. To keep things organized, I added a custom post type where I can add new delivery companies. The meta box in the order details shows me the companies I created. Everything's good, but I can't seem to get the delivery company info to show up in a new column in the orders list.

here is the code used to create the custom meta box.

```
added meta box with a drop-down list to choose in order details which company this order   
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_delivery_company_to_order' );
             function add_delivery_company_to_order() {
                add_meta_box(
                  'delivery_company_to_order',
                 'Delivery Company',
            'display_delivery_company_to_order',
            'shop_order',
            'side',
            'default'
        );
    }
    
    function display_delivery_company_to_order( $post ) {
        $delivery_companies = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'delivery_company',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        ) );
        $selected_delivery_company = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'delivery_company', true );
        echo '<select id="delivery_company" name="delivery_company">';
        echo '<option value="">' . __( 'Select a delivery company', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>';
        foreach ( $delivery_companies as $delivery_company ) {
            $selected = selected( $selected_delivery_company, $delivery_company->ID, false );
            echo '<option value="' . $delivery_company->ID . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $delivery_company->post_title . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
    
    add_action( 'save_post', 'save_delivery_company_to_order' );
    function save_delivery_company_to_order( $post_id ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( 'delivery_company', $_POST ) ) {
            update_post_meta(
                $post_id,
                'delivery_company',
                $_POST['delivery_company']
            );
        }
    }
```

here is the code used to create a new column to show the value

```
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_columns', 'add_delivery_company_column' );
function add_delivery_company_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_info ) {
        $new_columns[ $column_name ] = $column_info;
        if ( 'order_total' === $column_name ) {
            $new_columns['delivery_company'] = __( 'Delivery Company', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'display_delivery_company_in_order_list', 2 );
function display_delivery_company_in_order_list( $column ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'delivery_company' === $column ) {
        $delivery_company_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'delivery_company', true );
        if ( $delivery_company_id ) {
            $delivery_company = get_post( $delivery_company_id );
            echo $delivery_company->post_title;
        } else {
            echo '-';
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? thanks and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it here is the answer

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'delivery_company_order_column_content', 10, 2 );
function delivery_company_order_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    if ( $column === 'delivery_company_order' ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
        $delivery_company = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'delivery_company', true );
        $delivery_company_name = get_the_title( $delivery_company );
        echo $delivery_company_name;
    }
}

add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'delivery_company_order_column');
function delivery_company_order_column($columns)
{
    $columns['delivery_company_order'] = 'Delivery Company';
    return $columns;
}
```